# Replace selectbox content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I would like to replace whole content in my selectbox.

Here's what I have:

My new content looks like:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
Label: "A"
Value: 1
1: Object
Label: "B"
Value: 2
```

and I tried replace it this way:

```
var $el = $("#mySelectBoxId");
$el.empty();
$.each(newOptions, function (value, key) {
$el.append($("<option></option>")
.attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

And the result looks like list of Objects.

Comment: `$el.append($("<option></option>").val(key.Value).text(key.Label);` (the 1st parameter of the `.each` function is the index and the 2nd is the item)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsequm7b/)

```
var $el = $("#mySelectBoxId");
$el.empty();
$.each(newOptions, function(idx,item) {
  $el.append($("<option/>").attr("value", ""+item.Value+"").text(item.Label));
});
```